# What happened to Vijay Nadeer?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

Vijay Nadeer is (was?) an Inhuman who was the brother of the Inhuman-hating Senator Nadeer. She kindly shot him and dumped him in the ocean.

It was *heavily implied* that he survived, since upon hitting the bottom, he underwent Terrigenesis again (not the usual procedure for dead Inhumans), so it definitely seemed like he was alive and would show up again by the end of the season. We later saw a version of him within the Framework, where he was briefly seen captured and being experimented on by Hydra. However, despite expectations, the status of Vijay in the non-computerized world was not revealed.

Is there any information on what happened to Vijay? Is he (against all appearances) really dead? Or is this simply a dropped plot thread?

Comment: He'll come back in season 5 as Aquaman

Comment: @Derek - Possibly Namor, but not Aquaman.

Comment: Namor? Honestly, he seems like Darwin.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sequel hook, just like Ivanov's head and LMD production not being wrapped up but still out there.